# Algorithm to remove minimal subset to make sequence order

Tags: algorithm

I have a situation where I want to detect "outliers" in a supposedly sorted sequence. Elements that breaks the order are considered suspicious.

For example the sequence `1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 8, 9` is not sorted, but if you remove the `7` you get a sorted sequence `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9`, this is also true if you remove `5` and `6`, but that is more than just removing the `7` (also when having a sorted sequence you can remove arbitrary elements and still have a sorted sequence).

Is there an efficient algorithm for doing this? Is there an algorithm that finds all equally good solutions?

The later is for example if you have the sequence `1, 3, 2, 4`. You could remove `3` to get a sorted sequence, but you could also remove just `2` to get a sorted sequence (both solutions are equally good since they only removes one element).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in `O(N²)` by dynamic program or memoized recursion. If `foo(n,m)` represents maximum length of sorted subset (I think sub sequence is the correct word) from index `n` when index of last element added was `m`  then recursive function is:

```
int foo(int n,int m) {
   int res = 0;
   // you can add this number in the current sequence 
   //if its greater than the previous element in the sequence
   // seq is array containing the numbers
   if (seq[n] >= seq[m]) {
       //1 because we added this element
       // second argument is n because n is now the last element added
       res = 1 + foo (n+1, n);
   }
   // you can always skip the current element
   // in that case m remains same
   res = max (res, foo(n+1, m))

}
```

You will need to handle corner cases (index equal to array length) and add memoization to make it work but I will leave that to you. Also the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) page has even faster implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to finding longest increasing subsequence.

Ref for O(n^2) implementation : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-3-longest-increasing-subsequence/

and http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-size-n-log-n/ for nlog(n) implementation.